# How to `wget` a list of URLs in a text file?

Tags: text, wget

Let's say I have a text file of hundreds of URLs in one location, e.g.

```
http://url/file_to_download1.gz
http://url/file_to_download2.gz
http://url/file_to_download3.gz
http://url/file_to_download4.gz
http://url/file_to_download5.gz
....
```

What is the correct way to download each of these files with `wget`? I suspect there's a command like `wget -flag -flag text_file.txt`

Comment: Anybody end up here after trying to get US topos at nationalmap.gov?

Comment: Besides wget -i, You'll want to add some switches so you don't get banned from the servers for hammering them! And so that if it can't download one it doesn't keep trying for too long  `-w and -t and -T` may be of interest

Answer (score 297, accepted):

Quick `man wget` gives me the following:

> [..]
>
> -i *file*
>
> --input-file=*file*
>
> Read URLs from a local or external file. If - is specified as file, URLs are read from the standard input. (Use ./- to read from a file literally named -.)
>
> If this function is used, no URLs need be present on the command line. If there are URLs both on the command line and in an input file, those on the command lines will be the first ones to be retrieved. If --force-html is not specified, then file should consist of a series of URLs, one per line.
>
> [..]

So: `wget -i text_file.txt`

Comment: Is there a way to control the number of concurrent jobs?

Comment: Check the answer below by @Yusef: `cat text_file.txt | parallel --gnu "wget {}"`

Comment: Is there a way to rename each downloaded file according to some pattern? Perhaps, somehow using `-O`?

Answer (score 62):

try:

```
wget -i text_file.txt
```

(check man wget)

Answer (score 31):

If you also want to preserve the original file name, try with:

```
wget --content-disposition --trust-server-names -i list_of_urls.txt
```

Answer (score 29):

Run it in parallel with

```bash
cat text_file.txt | parallel --gnu "wget {}"
```

Comment: If Parallel's demand for citation is annoying, use xargs: `cat text_file.txt | xargs -n10 -P4 wget`. This tells xargs to call wget with 10 URLs and run 4 wget processes at a time. For a little bit nicer experience, here's what I do: `cat text_file.txt | shuf | xargs -n10 -P4 wget --continue`. This (1) shuffles the URLs so when you stop and restart, it's more likely to start downloading new files right away, and (2) it asks wget to `continue` partial downloads (you might get some if you Control-C while wget is downloading).

Answer (score 10):

If you're on **OpenWrt** or using some old version of wget which doesn't gives you `-i` option:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
input="text_file.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  wget $line
done < "$input"
```

Furthermore, if you don't have `wget`, you can use `curl` or whatever you use for downloading individual files.

Comment: if you;re here in 2023 and getting headaches about why a simple `curl -O "$line"` is giving errors like `curl: Failed to extract a sensible file name from the URL to use for storage!` and `curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL` - check the line endings in the source file (my text files were set to CRLF, they parsed fine when set to LF)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and while you can use wget -i, in my case there were many google drive docs URLs. So I used gdown (`pip install gdown`) combined with [@0x48piraj solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56465037). You must use the fuzzy option to follow and extract the redirect link provided by google.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
while IFS= read -r line
do
  gdown --fuzzy $line
done < "$input"
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to cat command to read the url.txt file and xargs it into wget, here is the command:

```bash
cat url.txt | xargs wget -r
```

cat reads all the list of urls then it used as input to `wget -r`.