# Bash script for downloading multiple files from a list

Tags: bash, macos, youtube-dl

Hope you all are doing well. I was wondering if you can write a bash script that kind of looks like this

The caveat is that I will be wanting to download videos, so it would be using youtube-dl

TOPIC1

HTTP:....

HTTP:...

TOPIC2

HTTP:...

HTTP:...

TOPIC3

HTTP:...

HTTP:...

Etc, etc.

I have all of these saved in a text file, and I would like a bash script that will create a directory with the TOPIC name as the folder, and then download each of the URLS under TOPIC and then move on to the next one, create a directory and then download all the URLS for that.

Does that make sense? I have very, very minimal experience with bash.

I could easily download just one using the youtube-dl command, but having to do that one at a time would be very cumbersome.

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: You may take advantage from posts like [How to `wget` a list of URLs in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986340/) or [Download files from a list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103623/).

Comment: Right on to both, appreciate the direction! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an executable bash script to solve your problem, paste this block of code into a file called 'download.sh' in the same directory where you have your 'links.txt' doc:

```
#!/bin/bash
topics=($(grep -v "http" links.txt))
for ((i = 0 ; i < ${#topics[@]} ; i++))
do
mkdir ${topics[$i]}
cd ${topics[$i]}
sed -n "/^${topics[$i]}/,/^${topics[$i+1]}/p" ../links.txt |\
sed '1d;$d' > to_be_downloaded.txt
youtube-dl -a to_be_downloaded.txt
rm to_be_downloaded.txt
cd ../
done
```

Save the script, then change the permissions of the script to 'executable' by pasting this into the terminal:

`chmod +x download.sh`

And then execute the script from the terminal:

`./download.sh`

As before, this will fail on the last topic in your links.txt file: do these missing urls manually. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: This was awesome! Thank you so much, works just as expected

Answer (score 1):

This solution relies on splitting your text file into chunks then passing the URLs to youtube-dl using the '-a' function:

> -a, --batch-file FILE            File containing URLs to download ('-' for
>                                    stdin), one URL per line. Lines starting
>                                    with '#', ';' or ']' are considered as
>                                    comments and ignored.

```
topics=($(grep -v "http" file))
for ((i = 0 ; i < ${#topics[@]} ; i++))
do
mkdir ${topics[$i]}
cd ${topics[$i]}
sed -n "/^${topics[$i]}/,/^${topics[$i+1]}/p" ../file |\
sed '1d;$d' > to_be_downloaded.txt
youtube-dl -a to_be_downloaded.txt
rm to_be_downloaded.txt
cd ../
done
```

This will fail on the last topic in "file" (your list): do these missing urls manually. It should work as requested for all others.

Comment: @jpman1 - I appreciate the response mate! Cheers. So I have saved the above script to an sh file and I'm executing as: `bash download.sh -a --batch-file links.txt` 

I get an error `grep: file: No such file or directory`; probably cuz I don't know what I'm doing lol

Comment: No problem; the code above was designed to be copy-pasted into a bash terminal after adapting it to suit your needs. I'll add another answer below with instructions on how to make it into a bash script and how to execute it.